# Not able to get large data from weblogic server11g version 10.3.5

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

We have deployed our EJB application on weblogic server 11g version 10.3.5, and we are using the java swing client to access the application on the server.

There when we try to make the "%" search call in one of the client request, the client never receives the data and then throws the PeerGoneException. But when I looked at the server everything is fine, there is no memory overrun or and there are sufficient execute threads available. Following is the Thread dump I found on the server. The last state of the thread is the socket write operation. But it never ends.

Could it be a network problem or the problem with weblogic configuration? Also, this is happening only on the SUN machine where we have installed the weblogic server. On our windows machine its working fine:

```
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" RUNNABLE native         
            java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)          
            java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)          
            java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)          
            weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.internalWrite(SocketMuxer.java:1005)          
            weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.write(SocketMuxer.java:997)                         weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3$T3MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.sendMsg(MuxableSocketT3.java:462)                         weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.sendOutMsg(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:336)                        weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.sendMsg(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:194)                       weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.sendMsg(MsgAbbrevJVMConnection.java:144)          
            weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.sendMsg(ConnectionManager.java:599)          
            weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.send(RJVMImpl.java:903)                          weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevOutputStream.flushAndSend(MsgAbbrevOutputStream.java:394)          
            weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevOutputStream.send(MsgAbbrevOutputStream.java:445)          
            weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.postInvoke(BasicServerRef.java:693)          
            weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:537)          
            weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)          
            weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)          
            weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Comment: Did you try enabling debug logging to narrow down the issue? The thread dump is a bit generic but it's probably clustering or connectivity related.

Comment: Hi Zahir, as you suggested I enabled debug looging in the weblogic server on SUN solaris machine. After that I found that there were below warning messages: BEA-000450  Socket 288 internal data record unavailable (probable closure due idle timeout), event received -32 .      And these messages came for many sockets(around 8 to 10 messages with different socket numbers). Please provide your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer.

PeerGoneException is due to the socket closure. The communication is broken when the server can't take the request ( for e.g. when the MaxMessageSize exceeds the default (10MB) or if overridden through -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize system property).